# Alternatives for MBProgressHUD?

Tags: iphone, ios4, mbprogresshud

I've used SVProgressHUD which I liked but it didn't support orientation changes. I am using MBProgressHUD but it is a modal HUD.

Is there any good alternative to these? I need the HUD to be non-modal and needs to support orientation changes.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Simply setting:

```
HUD.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

is all it takes to achieve a non-modal behavior (allow touches to pass through the HUD). You don't even have to modify the actual MBProgressHUD code.

Comment: Thanks. I believe you're the one who added all those fixes in the HUD last month and I'm using your branch since it has newer fixes.

Comment: This isn't really a fix. It's standard UIKit behavior inherited from UIView. You're right regarding the fork though, I haven't pulled the latest changes into the main repository yet.

Answer (score 30):

[SVProgressHUD](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD) now **does** support orientation change. Sorry it took so long.

Comment: I use it and love it for its simplicity; especially when I needed singleton object, which MBProgressView didn't support.

Answer (score 5):

There's about half a dozen alternatives here: http://cocoacontrols.com/search?q=progress&commit=Search

...although most are modal. But it would be fairly straightforward to adapt to be non-modal. Hopefully one of the libraries at the link above will serve you better anyway.

Answer (score 1):

MBProgressHUD does support orientation changes and is modal in a way that takes whole screen with invisible view. There's source code available, modify it.

Comment: As TheBlack says, as far as I can tell MBProgressHUD now handles rotation without any problems.

Comment: I believe the comments about orientation support were regarding `SVProgressHUD`. In any case, both libraries now support orientation changes.

Answer (score 0):

A viable alternative written completely in Swift could be [IHProgressHUD](https://github.com/Swiftify-Corp/IHProgressHUD). Minimum Swift 4.2 required